# Vaadin - Multiple Files Upload

Tags: button, upload, vaadin

Using the Vaadin component Upload it creates a button next to the Browse button that let you choose the file to upload. The thing is that I need to upload multiple files, and this involves only one Upload button at the end! I thought I could make a button at the end calling the .startUpload(). However, creating multiple Upload() objects would still show a button next to each line (next to each Browse button)... how do I hide the button creted by the Upload() default Vaadin class?

---

Yeah sorry for the newbie question man... I just put the file into /lib and I just used the UploadField class without any widgetset... what I don't get is why when I go like:

```
Button b = new Button("Show value");
        b.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Object value = uploadField.getValue();
                Notification.show("Value:" + value);
            }
        });
        wrapper.addComponents(uploadField, b);
```

And I click the button (once I choose the file to upload) instead of giving me the file name or whatever the method uploadField.getValuie() would return, I get a massive popup with loads of no sense chars...???

Comment: Update: Vaadin Flow (versions 10+) has a new `Upload` component, significantly enhanced in Vaadin 14.1. Use the [live demo](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-upload/java-examples) to upload multiple image files for display. The button presents a file-picker dialog in which the user can select multiple files. Also, the user can drag-and-drop a folder or multiple files from the host OS file system (such as the Finder in macOS).

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of file upload in HTML browsers.

Look at this component, it provides a better way for the users to upload files.

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/easyuploads

Comment: I already had a look there... the thing is that I have to use Maven to interact with that add-on...and that's really annoying!!! I was then looking for another solution... any other hint?

Comment: Why maven ?
You just need to put in your lib directory and then recompile the widgetset.
Maven is just one of the options to do the gwt widgetset compilation.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the newbie question man... I just put the file into /lib and I just used the UploadField class without any widgetset... what I don't get is why when I go like: